# Proving inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given that  $q \ge 0$, $p \ge 0$, prove
$$\sqrt{q} + \sqrt{p} \le \sqrt{2qp}.$$
I tried
$$(\sqrt{q}+ \sqrt{p})^2 \le (\sqrt {2qp})^2 ,$$
$$ q+2\sqrt{qp}+p \le 2qp,$$
How can I continue? Could you help me in solving this problem?

Comment: Your inequality is wrong. Check for $p=4,q=9$.

Comment: Or $p=q=1$ for that matter.

Comment: Or $p=1$ and $q=0$  :D

Comment: Why does p=q=0 work?

Comment: Because $0+0=0$?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps OP meant to write $p+q \geq 2\sqrt{pq}$, a well known inequality (called AM-GM). Your method was very close to the most common proof of the inequality, namely that

$p+q \geq 2\sqrt{pq}$

$p^2 + 2pq + q^2 \geq 4pq$

$p^2 - 2pq + q^2 \geq 0$

$(p-q)^2 \geq 0$

Which is always true because real numbers when squared always yield positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Is false: if $p=q$
$$2\sqrt{p} = \sqrt{q} + \sqrt{p}\le\sqrt{2qp} = \sqrt{2}p,$$
i.e.,
$$\sqrt{2}\le\sqrt{p},$$
so the inequality is false for $0\le p = q<2$

Comment: What if it is $\sqrt{q} + \sqrt{p} \ge \sqrt{2pq} $instead?

Comment: @User2524, also false. Use the same trick.